# Lexer rule -> Get only content of string

Tags: java, antlr

I've this lexer rule on my grammar:

```
STRING_LITERAL
 : '\'' ( ~'\'' | '\'\'' )* '\''
 ;
```

When I visit this rule, I want to get the "content" of this `STRING_LITERAL`. So, that's everything between first `'` and the last `'`.

Example:

```
String s = node.getText();
s -> "'sample string'"
```

Is it possible to touch a bit the Lexer rule in order to get the "content" of the string?

Comment: Do no try to put too much "intelligence" into the Lexer. This can be handled elsewhere.

Comment: Could you tell me what are you thinking about? How can I get a slighter `STRING_LITERAL` lexer rule?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply strip the quotes when you read out the text in your listener/walker/whatever-consume-code? ibre5041 is right, don't put too much processing in the grammar. The semantic phase is a much better place for that.